# How to cache images & data in Pager Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

The following is my pager adapter class, It gets called every time user goes to event Activity. There are around 20 images in this activity, I fetched them from the server and save them locally in my app. So next time it does not hit the service, but still it takes time to render these 20 images, Is there a way I can also cache these images, so on second run it does not call `instantiateItem` 20 times.

```
  public class MynPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context mContext;


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.team_event_homescreen,container,false);

        ImagesLoader.getInstance(mContext).getImage("MyName").setBmpToImageView(homeImageView);
        ImagesLoader.getInstance(mContext).getImage(currentEvent.oppLogoName).setBmpToImageView(awayImageView);

           }        


}
```

Kindly guide me a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of ImageLoader but in Glide the image generally remains in memory even after the activity destroyed. May be using the applicationcontext in glide with method can load images instantaneously on second run of activity